# Wordpress Get FTP Credentials from Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin with integrated client that allows syncing of audio files into an archive.

I want to be able to auto generate a config for the client on the backend

in order to do this I need to be able to retrieve the FTP Connection info and credentials, does anyone have any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Thanks
Marley

Comment: Hey Marley! What's the process here? Are you using WordPress to retrieve files from a remote location using FTP credentials or is something else going on?

Comment: The files are synced onto the server using a python client, they are then imported into a custom post type. the client reads a config.json file and I want to be able to generate this in the wordpress backend in order to make setup easy for the end user

Comment: AFAIK, WordPress has no FTP credentials stored anywhere by default.

Comment: wordpress uses ftp to install plugins and themes. is there no way for me to retrieve these?

Comment: In my experience, FTP credentials are not common. Could you instead create an upload endpoint to ingest the files and generate the config.json for the client at the same time?

Comment: @Rohjay could you point me in the right direction on how I could do this safely and securely?

Comment: That's a big question for a little text box. A simple endpoint that the python client could post to would probably do fine unless you have file size limitations from your host. Check out the rest api docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ . Regarding the config, I'm not sure what you need to give you any real help there. For more help, I might suggest the WordPress Chat discord server - folks there are generally pretty helpful.